# JAVA. Validating if 2nd index is less than 1st index?

Tags: java

In my code I want a user to enter 3 inputs to extract a substring based on the 2nd two inputs which will be int variables. I have most of the validation covered but if a user enters a 2nd index less than the first then a error is returned any ides on how to fix this ?

```
System.out.println("Enter the 2nd index of the word : ");
endIndex = scanner.nextInt();

while (endIndex > inputString.length()) {
    System.out.println("Index is not in string length, try again.");
    System.out.println("Enter the second index of the substring : ");
    endIndex = scanner.nextInt();
} 

char[] ch = new char[endIndex - startIndex + 1];
inputString.getChars(startIndex, endIndex + 1, ch, 0);

System.out.println("Output : " + String.valueOf(ch));
```

Comment: What are `inputString` and `startIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

Check that condition in the `while` as well

```
while (endIndex > inputString.length() || endIndex < startIndex + 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Ironic how you assure you validate your code when you clearly are missing validation for these two integers...

Anyway, you need to validate startIndex when you are acquiring it. You have two alternatives:

- When you acquire endIndex you check if it is smaller than startIndex

  `while (endIndex > inputString.length() || endIndex < startIndex + 1)`
- Right before `getChars` you check these two values and swap them if `startIndex` > `endIndex`.

Also:

- You are not validating if they are negative.
- You are using a `while` as it was a `do - while`